# iOS - Firebase storage download very slow

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm using Firebase Storage for my app. In my app a user has a profile and can upload a profile photo and then when they click on their profile in the future, it should download and display their profile picture. The problem is that when I upload and download the photo there is a significant delay and it appears the code isn't running when it should. For the download, I have the call in my `ViewWillAppear()`, however it continues running even after the screen has loaded and I am clicking on other things. How can I speed this up? Not only is the delay annoying, but it causes crashes when I move to another view or logout and the code in `ViewWillAppear()` is still running.

```
override func viewWillAppear(bool: Bool) {

    var retPic : UIImage
    let storage = FIRStorage.storage()

    let storageRef = storage.referenceForURL("gs://project-xxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com")

    let profPicRef = storageRef.child("images/" + (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)! + ".jpg")
    // Download in memory with a maximum allowed size of 1MB (1 * 1024 * 1024 bytes)

    profPicRef.dataWithMaxSize(1 * 4096 * 4096) { (data, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error)
        } else {
            // Data for "images/island.jpg" is returned
            print("This is delayed")
            self.retPic = UIImage(data: data!)!
            self.imageView.image = self.retPic
                     print("still here")
            self.imageView.reloadInputViews()   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How big is the file? What type of network are you downloading it over? Internet speed is likely your biggest slowdown. Especially on a mobile device, this is fairly limited.

Comment: The file is not too big, it is just a regular iphone photo. Is there any way to at least force the method to stop executing when I switch screens? Or any way at all to speed this up?

Comment: I checked with some of our engineers. The best bet is that your roundtrips to the GCS server (where the file is uploaded to) is slow. There is nothing you can do to change that. While we also can't change the roundtrip speed (or the bandwidth for that matter), we are looking into ways to optimize for such scenarios. For downloads you could try [downloading from a downloadURL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#generate_a_download_url) with a download library (such as SDWebImage) to see if that removes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's mostly likely a combination of a) How big the data is you're trying to download is, b) What kind of network you're on, c) Where you're located, and d) What your definition of "slow" is. :)

That said, a "regular iPhone photo" is really freakin' big -- the iPhone 6s, for instance, takes photos that are 4032 x 3024. And my guess is your imageView is a whole lot smaller than that. So one suggestion is to resize your image *before* you upload it to Firebase Storage based on the image size you think you'll eventually need.

I also agree with Frank that using the `downloadURL` in combination with a library like `SDWebImage`, `PINRemoteImage`, or `AlamoFireImage` is probably a good idea. These libraries take care of important tasks like loading off the main thread, caching, and generally not crashing if your target imageView suddenly disappears.

Answer (score -1):

You should use background thread when convert NSData to UIImage or you can fetch image url and use Kingfisher pod. I prefer second option.

**Swift3 Version:**

```
import Kingfisher

profPicRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in

   if error != nil {

       print(error)
   }
   else{

       let retPicUrl = (url?.absoluteString)! as String

    self.imageView.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: retPicUrl)!)
    self.imageView.reloadInputViews() 

   }
 })
```